# Minimum eigenvalue as a lower bound for strict convexity parameter

Tags: calculus, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization

Say $ f(x) = x A x^T $ is a strictly convex function. How can I prove that I can obtain a lower bound on the strictly convexity parameter of the function, if I know the minimum eigenvalue of the matrix $A$, where $A$ is the matrix associated with the quadratic form. So $\mu \geq \lambda_{\min}(A)$, where $\mu$ is the strictly convexity parameter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is a "strictly convexity parameter"?